# My kubuntu crashed and now it doesn't show the login screen

Tags: boot, kubuntu, plymouth

I use Kubuntu 20.04

Due to power outage my laptop stopped booting. It hangs/stops before it reaches the login screen. I think it's plymouth which got corrupted.

I booted into safe mode and checked and I see no plymouth under lib (/lib/plymouth)

From safe mode I tried to enable networking but it failed. So that means I can't do a "apt install plymouth-x11" either.

When I turned on verbose in grub, these are the last lines where it hangs

> ... ... [Ok] Started Bluetooth management mechanism [Ok] Started snap
> daemon
> Starting Wait until snaps is fully seeded... [Ok] Finished Wait until snapd is fully seeded

And the cursor just hangs here.
I am lost. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: If I have a power outage, or anything that maybe have resulted in an *unclean* shutdown, I don't boot into the system until i've performed a *file-system-check* (`fsck`).  If problems are detected & fixed, the next boot is normally normal. If it's `plymouth`, I wouldn't have changed packages, but just had your system boot without using it (ie. `nosplash` & remove 'quiet` from kernel line). I can't see `plymouth` issues causes boot to hang (you usually just get a plymouth error hiding the normal kernel boot messages instead of graphic) so I think you've been changing unrelated packages

Comment: I did that too, and it just hangs at the "Started bluetooth management" and the boot process doesn't move forward

Comment: I am not able to connect to the net too. When I gave ifconfig it just shows lo, there is nothing else, no eth0 nor wlan0. In the recovery menu when I selected "enable networking", it blinked and came back to the same screen.

Comment: In my case, I still can enter the console with "ctrl+alt+F1" and do apt install there...